# How do get element out of xml file

Tags: vb.net, web-services, xpath, reference

I get an XML file From a web service. Now I want to get one of those elements out of the file.

I think I should go use XPath - any good starter reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not VB specific, but try this: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 2):

I've just been recovering my XPath skills- this [Xslt and XPath Quick Reference sheet](http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/) is quite a useful reference - it doesn't go into depth but it does list what is available and what you might want to search for more information on.

The w3schools tutorial linked previously isn't that great - it takes a long time to not cover a lot of ground - but it is still worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to only extract the needed informations with an xslt file into a new xml and use this new xml as data basis for further processing

Answer (score 0):

If I need to do some XPath, I just tweak one of these examples.

- **child::node()** selects all the children of the context node, whatever their node type
- **attribute::name** selects the name attribute of the context node
- **attribute::*** selects all the attributes of the context node
- **descendant::para** selects the para element descendants of the context node
- **ancestor::div** selects all **div** ancestors of the context node
- **ancestor-or-self::div** selects the **div** ancestors of the context node and, if the context node is a div element, the context node as well
- **descendant-or-self::para** selects the **para** element descendants of the context node and, if the context node is a **para** element, the context node as well
- **self::para** selects the context node if it is a **para** element, and otherwise selects nothing
- **child::chapter/descendant::para** selects the **para** element descendants of the chapter element children of the context node
- **child::*/child::para** selects all **para** grandchildren of the context node
- **/** selects the document root (which is always the parent of the document element)
- **/descendant::para** selects all the **para** elements in the same document as the context node
- **/descendant::olist/child::item** selects all the item elements that have an **olist** parent and that are in the same document as the context node
- **child::para[position()=1]** selects the first **para** child of the context node
- **child::para[position()=last()]** selects the last **para** child of the context node
- **child::para[position()=last()-1]** selects the last but one **para** child of the context node
- **child::para[position()>1]** selects all the **para** children of the context node other than the first para child of the context node
- **following-sibling::chapter[position()=1]** selects the next **chapter** sibling of the context node
- **preceding-sibling::chapter[position()=1]** selects the previous **chapter** sibling of the context node
- **/descendant::figure[position()=42]** selects the forty-second figure element in the document
- **/child::doc/child::chapter[position()=5]/child::section[position()=2]** selects the second section of the fifth **chapter** of the **doc** document element
- **child::para[attribute::type="warning"]** selects all **para** children of the context node that have a type attribute with value **warning**
- **child::para[attribute::type='warning'][position()=5]** selects the fifth **para** child of the context node that has a type attribute with value warning
- **child::para[position()=5][attribute::type="warning"]** selects the fifth **para** child of the context node if that child has a type attribute with value **warning**
- **child::chapter[child::title='Introduction']** selects the chapter children of the context node that have one or more title children with string-value equal to Introduction
- **child::chapter[child::title]** selects the **chapter** children of the context node that have one or more title children
- **child::*[self::chapter or self::appendix]** selects the **chapter** and **appendix** children of the context node
- **child::*[self::chapter or self::appendix][position()=last()]** selects the last **chapter** or **appendix** child of the context node

An in depth documentation can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath). Also these example are taken from there.